# How can I bundle up the input data by users and the numbers generated by my sudoku generator, and pass them to Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, sudoku

I've made the sudoku generator and the templates, but now I stuck in posting the whole array(9x9) to Django (i.e. sudoku_checker) for checking the duplicates and determine whether the user can go next game.

Here is my template looks like in Django, and you'll see I've indexed/positioned every single table cell, thought it might help with later checking:

```html
 <table>
          <caption>Sudoku of the day</caption>
          {% for row in numbers %}
            <tr>
                {% for col in row %}
                {% if col is 0 %}
                <td>
                    <input class="d0" size="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" name="{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                </td>
                {% else %}
                <td id="{{ forloop.parentloop.counter0 }}{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ col }}</td>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

but then what should I do next? Am I correct to use Form method to Post the data to Django? But how can i make sure all the data have been bundled up when passing through for checking, in terms of both the known numbers and unknown numbers(input by users)? any hints please?

This is the code of the views, but i only completed the numbers_fill_table one, i dont know what to write in second part of views and forms properly to post the exact data i want. Please help!

```
from .sudoku_generator import sudoku_generator

def board_fill(request):

    context = {'numbers': sudoku_generator.final_board()}
    template = 'sudoku_board.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: The POST is correct. What kind of view do you have that is getting the request. Could you post code?

Comment: @JuhoRutila hello just updated the codes :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you have the view (you must map it to the url that is used as the form target) it gets the request object. From there you can read the user input:

```
request.POST.get('44', 0) # Will return 0 if 44 is not found
```

More hint about writing a view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/ and mapping the view to the url: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/